# Javascript beforesend function incorrectly displayed on all "add to cart" buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, opencart

On my ecommerce webshop, I have a page where some products are listed row by row in a table. After each product, there is an "add to cart" button displayed. When a visitor clicks the add to cart button of a specific product, then the corresponding "add to cart" button should temporarily change in "... loading" before the product is effectively added to the cart. The problem on my page is that ALL "add to cart" button are showing the "...loading" message when only one of the buttons is clicked (see picture below).

[image]

I have no idea how to solve this. Please find the corresponding piece of code below. I hope somebody can point me in the correct direction. The product itself however (and only this product) is correctly added to the cart.

Thanks,
SabKo

The HTML:

```
<? $r=($page-1)*20+1; foreach($products AS $product){ ?> 
<tr id="row_<?=$product['product_id']?>">
    <td class="center">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$product['product_id']?>" size="2" name="product_id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$product['gift_products_id']?>" size="2" name="gift_products_id" />
        <? if($product['quantity']!==$product['total']){  ?>
        <select name="quantity" class="form-control_cart" id="input-quantity" value="1" >
             <?php foreach (range(1, $product['quantity'], 1) as $stap) {
                  if ($stap == 1) {
                        echo "<option value='$stap' selected>$stap</option>";
                  } else {
                        echo "<option value='$stap'>$stap</option>";
                  }
                }  ?>
        </select>
        <a class="btn btn-default addtocart" style="margin-top:-4px" lang="<?=$product['product_id']?>" href="javascript:void(0)"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?=$_['gr_m_add_to_cart']?>"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>                       
    </td>
</tr>
<? $r++;} ?>
```

The javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.deletelink').click(function(){
    if(confirm('<?=$_['gr_remove_q']?>')){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}            
  });
$('.addtocart').click(function() {

id = $(this).attr('lang');

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#row_'+id+' input[type=\'text\'], #row_'+id+' input[type=\'hidden\'], #row_'+id+' select'),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.addtocart').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('.addtocart').button('reset');
    },
    success: function(json) {
        $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

        if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['option']) {
                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                    var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));

                    if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
                        element.parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                    } else {
                        element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                    }
                }
            }

            if (json['error']['recurring']) {
                $('select[name=\'recurring_id\']').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</div>');
            }

            // Highlight any found errors
            $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
        }

        if (json['success']) {
            if (!Journal.showNotification(json['success'], json['image'])) {
                $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
            }

            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

            $('#cart ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.addtocart')` matches *all* the buttons. You need to select just the one they clicked on.

```
$('.addtocart').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('lang');
    var self = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#row_'+id+' input[type=\'text\'], #row_'+id+' input[type=\'hidden\'], #row_'+id+' select'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            self.button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            self.button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));

                        if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
                            element.parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                        } else {
                            element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (json['error']['recurring']) {
                    $('select[name=\'recurring_id\']').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</div>');
                }

                // Highlight any found errors
                $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                if (!Journal.showNotification(json['success'], json['image'])) {
                    $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                }

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                $('#cart ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with your selector.

You are using this selector:

`$('.addtocart').button('loading');`, which is class based and will grab any element with this class in the DOM.
You are using the `.click` functionality. (It's old and won't work anymore in jquery 3.x. You should really switch to `$('.element').on("click, function(){//function});`

Instead, use this:

```
beforeSend: function() {
  $(this).button('loading');
},
complete: function() {
  $(this).button('reset');
},
```

however, it would be even neater to do it like this:

```
$('.addtocart').click(function() {
  obj = $(this);
  id = $(this).attr('lang');
//..the rest of your code..
obj.button('load'); //etc
```

Comment: `$(this)` won't work because it's in a callback function.

Comment: Then you could use the obj. method I just added into my answer. It will place the `$(this)` element into a variable which you'll be able to use through the entire scope of the function.

Comment: I know that, I did it in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were OP replying to me. I actually didn't even see your answer, hahaha. Now it looks like I copied it off of you. I didn't, though. But sorry! I'll upvote yours to make it up to you :)

Comment: Hello Barnar and Barnadead, thanks for your very prompt answers. I tried Barnar's solution and it works fine. I suppose also Babydead's solution will work also, Thanks. SabKo!